# Change ActionBar tab text size

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I create tab in my action bar by doing

```
ActionBar.Tab incidentsTab = bar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.incTab));
    ActionBar.Tab apparatusTab = bar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.appTab));
    ActionBar.Tab adminTab = bar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.adminTab));
    ActionBar.Tab claemgTab = bar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.calTab));

    currentIncTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());
    incidentsTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());
    apparatusTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());
    adminTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());
    claemgTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());
    bar.addTab(currentIncTab, true);
    bar.addTab(incidentsTab, false);
    bar.addTab(apparatusTab, false);
    bar.addTab(adminTab, false);
    bar.addTab(claemgTab, false);
```

now is there a way to change the size of the next slightly after doing this?

Answer (score 0):

set the android:theme to the  in Manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".app.ActionBarTabs"
    android:label="@string/action_bar_tabs"       
    android:theme="@style/TestHoloTheme"        
    android:enabled="@bool/atLeastHoneycomb">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And add this to the styles.xml

```
<style name="TestHoloTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTabText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">24px</item>
</style>
```

And add this to the attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="TestCustom">
    <attr name="actionBarTabTextStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From [the official site of android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Be careful, the attribute "android:actionBarTabTextStyle" must be defined inside the parent theme style not the actionbar style in order for this to work.